# finding substring in string in shell script not working

Tags: shell, unix

I have a test.cfg file whose contents are:

```
product_identifier=XR656_HD;G6_656
program_family=STR
```

and a script file as

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_FILE="test.cfg"
getValueforKeyInProdConfig ()
{
        key=$1
        if [ -e $CONFIG_FILE ]; then
                value=`cat  $CONFIG_FILE | grep $key | cut -d "=" -f2 | tr -d '\r'`
                echo "$value"
        else
                echo ""
        fi
}

product_identifier="$(getValueforKeyInProdConfig "product_identifier")"
program_family="$(getValueforKeyInProdConfig "program_family")"

echo "product_identifier=$product_identifier"
echo "program_family=$program_family"

if [[ ( $program_family == "STR" ) && ( ($product_identifier == *"G6_656"*) || ($product_identifier == *"G6_646"*) ) ]]; then
        echo "found string"
else
        echo "unknown"
fi
```

But the output is:

```
product_identifier=XR656_HD;G6_656
program_family=STR
unknown
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
found string
```

How should I compare substring in bash to make the script working

Comment: I ran the program as-is and it worked for me (on Mac). I got:
```product_identifier=XR656_HD;G6_656
program_family=STR
found string```

Can you please try it on another machine?

Comment: `value=$(grep $key); value="${value##*=}";` (*Parameter Expansion with substring removal*)

Comment: issue was with whitespace, was not working since there was whitespace after the first line in the cfg file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just source your CONFIG_FILE?

```
$ cat test.cfg
product_identifier='XR656_HD;G6_656'
program_family=STR
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_FILE="test.cfg"
. "$CONFIG_FILE"

echo product_identifier=$product_identifier
echo program_family=$program_family

[[ $program_family     == "STR"       ]] && \
[[ $product_identifier =~ .*G6_6[45]6 ]] && \
echo "found string" || echo "unknown"
```

Testing

```
$ ./test 
product_identifier=XR656_HD;G6_646
program_family=STR
found string

$ ./test 
product_identifier=XR656_HD;G6_656
program_family=STR
found string

$ ./test 
product_identifier=XR656_HD;G6_676
program_family=STR
unknown

$ ./test
product_identifier=XR656_HD;G6_656
program_family=fail
unknown
```